# Remote Genymotion device connection failed for API21

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, genymotion

I have a Genymotion device in another local PC (due to slow performance) and Android Studio in another development PC. I can connect any Genymotion device which is below API21 from my development PC (using **adb connect 192.168.x.x**) but any device with API21 shows offline in my development PC, though adb can connect well. In the "device choose" panel and device monitor, it shows `offline`. But in the remote PC, the same device is online and workable. Why does it show `online` for devices with API below 21, and `offline` for API 21+.
I get the following after connecting to my remote Genymotion device. But the same device works on that remote host well. Any devices below API21 shows `online`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got it right myself by trial n error.After connecting the remote genymotion device(API21),I found that there are several adb process in task manager for A SINGLE genymotion device.Then I manually stopped all "adb" process from windows task manager on remote machine (or adb kill-server command for all adb process,in my case there were more). Then using adb command I restarted and connected again the same remote device frm development machine. Somehow it is connected and shows ONLINE now and works as expected. I dont know why it happens to devices < API21. The other device >=API21 connects directly and shows online.The problem seems to be multiple adb process on remote machine for a single genymotion device of only API21.

Comment: I have tried to kill all adb instances on the Genymotion PC, but they restart themselves. So, I ended up by open Genymotion Settings -> ADB -> Custom Android SDK tools and left them empty. This prevented ADB from starting on next launches of Genymotion devices. Now I can connect to these devices via ADB remotely (from other PCs).

Comment: Thank you very much @Stan . Worked like a charm

Comment: This worked for me, BUT, the "adb push" command issued by Android Studio took an awful long time to push the 10meg apk to the remote GenyMotion emulator.  It eventually did it.  In the mean time, while trying to figure it out, I connected (adb shell) and navigated to the destination folder (/data/local/tmp) and watched it move data at about 2K/sec.  Also the keyboard response was very bad, as in seconds for my typing to show up.  Possibly due to the concurrent "push", but that was as I said very slow going.

Answer (score 2):

I tried both solutions (included the accepted one) and it didn't work. Finally found a solution to this one. After much fiddling, I found out that genymotion only allows `adb connection` from one machine at the time. Doing a `adb kill-server` on the host imediatelly followed by an `adb connect ip` on the remote machine did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to get adb over wifi working by renaming the adb binary in the genymotion\tools directory.

I also enabled adb over wifi from a terminal emulator on the Genymotion VM with the following commands:

su

setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555

stop adbd

start adbd

start adbd (just to be sure)

This is more reliable than using some of the adb over wifi apps :)

(Note that if you disable the genymotion player adb instance you will not now be able to connect to a local host ide )